# Selenium firefox exceed disk space with temporary files

Tags: python, linux, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm doing a lot of test automation stuff using python + selenium + firefox webdriver. A few time ago I noticed that sometimes my test system fails and stops working due to exceed /tmp directory space with a lot of tmpXXXXX directories on my linux machine. The solution was

```
rm -rf /tmp
```

This worked good enough till today when I had left many test instances at the same time for night. On the next morning I noticed all my tests failed with exception "Disk quota exceeded". Oooops. All my free disk space had left on /, /tmp, *scripts_directory* paths. This is very strange that the my /home disk where I ran my scripts had no free space too due to a tremendous number of tmpXXXXX folders there.
How did this happen?
I'm using

```
driver.quit()
```

instead of

```
driver.close()
```

In python scripts, but I have many web driver restarts and quits in script so now I see /tmp directory free space oscillate nearby a certain value and not constantly increased and on the next morning I see about 3 GBs are busy in /tmp directory. What is the clue of tmp files disaster?

Comment: I have the same issue and event posted on selenium google forum.  They are not responsive